# mysqld.sock not created on Galera node

Tags: docker, ansible, mariadb, galera

I have a Galera cluster running on MariaDB containers, and only the bootstrapping node accepts connections - the other ones don't create a socket.

I'm baffled by this behavior since all the nodes are created from the same VM template and have the same configuration (apart from `wsrep_cluster_address = gcomm://` in the bootstrapper node).

I'm using `mariadb/server:10.4` as the container image.

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (the only configuration file that exists and is the same across all nodes):

```
[mysqld]
port                     = 3306
report_host              = {{ ansible_host }} # always FQDN
default_storage_engine   = InnoDB
binlog_format            = ROW
character-set-server     = utf8mb4
character_set_server     = utf8mb4

[mariadb]
bind-address             = 0.0.0.0
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2

# Galera cluster configuration
wsrep_on                 = ON
wsrep_provider           = /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address    = gcomm://10.0.0.100,10.0.1.101,10.0.0.102,10.0.0.103
wsrep_cluster_name       = my-galera-cluster
wsrep_sst_method         = rsync
wsrep_sst_auth           = root:s3cr3t-r00t-p4ssw0rd

# Cluster node configuration
wsrep_node_address       = {{ inventory_hostname }} # always IP
wsrep_node_name          = {{ ansible_host.split(".")[0] | lower }} # always host name
```

This is how I run each node in Ansible:

```
- name: Start MariaDB docker container
  docker_container:
    image: "mariadb/server:10.4"
    name: "mariadb-server"
    state: started
    log_driver: json-file
    log_options:
      max-size: "100m"
      max-file: "2"
    env:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: "/etc/mysql/secrets/mariadb_root_password"
      MARIADB_USER: "my-user"
      MARIADB_PASSWORD_FILE: "/etc/mysql/secrets/mariadb_my-user_password"
      MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MARIADB_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      # https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/issues/262
      MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO: "1"
    volumes:
      - "/etc/mysql:/etc/mysql"
      - "/var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
    ports:
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}:3306:3306"
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}:4567:4567"
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}:4567:4567/udp"
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}:4568:4568"
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}:4444:4444"
```

When I check the cluster status on the bootstrapping node I get happy figures such as:

```
wsrep_cluster_size 4
wsrep_cluster_status Primary
wsrep_connected ON
wsrep_ready ON
```

The `mysqld` daemon is present on all nodes:

```
# docker exec mariadb-server ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mysql        1     0  0 07:12 ?        00:00:06 mysqld
mysql       46     1  0 07:12 ?        00:00:00 sh -c wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '10.0.1.102' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --parent '1'
mysql       47    46  0 07:12 ?        00:00:04 /bin/bash -ue /usr//bin/wsrep_sst_rsync --role joiner --address 10.0.1.102 --datadir /var/lib/mysql/ --parent 1
mysql       98    47  0 07:12 ?        00:00:00 rsync --daemon --no-detach --port 4444 --config /var/lib/mysql//rsync_sst.conf
mysql    16029    47  0 08:18 ?        00:00:00 sleep 1
root     16030     0  0 08:18 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Each of the containers has the default socket directory: `/var/run/mysqld`, yet only the bootstrapping node creates `mysqld.sock`, so trying to log in locally fails:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Even when I add `socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` to any section (`[mariadb]`, `[mysql]`, `[mysqld]`, `[client]`) it seems that the other nodes just skip its creation. The bootstrapping node is the only that produces this line in the log:

```
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'
```

How to make the other nodes create the socket too?
Important note: when I disable the Galera configuration each node creates a socket successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to directly installing MariaDB on the operating system with no containers and my issue with the socket was resolved... Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the socket path:

```sh
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -e "select @@socket"
```

If none is present, set the following and restart mysql:

```
[mysqld]
socket: /var/run/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: But that's the whole point :) I can't log in locally because the socket doesn't exist, so runnig `mysql` fails on `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`.
I didn't write it but explicitly writing the `socket` key was ignored for some reason.